# Action script, NativeProcess , resolvePath and swf does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I will expose my problem but first I have to show you my configuration to give you all the details.

I have 2 Virtual Machines, 2 windows 7. The first one, it is where I developp all my Action Scripts, where there is my Development Environment(IDE) and second one there is nothing special installed. On both there is Adobe AIR and Adobe Flash Player.

Ok, here is my problem. I develop (on first one) a script that uses NativeProcess to run a CMD.exe that load in command line a dll.
And when I Build&Run the project everything is ok, I check and the dll is loaded. But the problem is when the second Windows connected into my localhost website (to the first windows that play as a server) and run the file "myProgram.swf" (the ActionScript program) that do not load my dll.

Now I print you all my code :

This is the script that loads the dll "myProgram.swf" :

```
 public class NativeProcessExample extends Sprite
{
    public var process:NativeProcess;

    public function NativeProcessExample()
    {
        if(NativeProcess.isSupported)
        {
            setupAndLaunch();
        }
        else
        {
            trace("NativeProcess not supported.");
        }
    }

    public function setupAndLaunch():void
    {     

        var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();

        fmt.size = 32;
        txt.text = 'Hello, world!' + '\n' +
            'Width = ' + stage.fullScreenWidth + '\n' +
            'Height = ' + stage.fullScreenHeight;
        txt.setTextFormat(fmt);
        txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

        addChild(txt);


        var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\regsvr32.exe");
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;


        var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        args.push("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Downloads\\myDLL.dll");
        nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = args;
        var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
        process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
        process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, exitHandler);
```

I cut (I deleted all includes and end part) the script cause its too long but here is the most interesting part.

Now I will show you my "index.php" where the 2nd Windows connected to recover and inject the dll. :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
            <style type=\"text/css\">
                    body, html
                    {
                            width:100%;
                            height:100%;
                            overflow:hidden;
                    }
                    #SWFSquare
                    {
                            height: 200px;
                            width: 200px;
                            background-color: blue;
                    }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffdfaf">



    <div id="SWFSquare">
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Download" id="buttonDownload" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;">

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {

            $("#buttonDownload").click(function() {
                    window.open("myDLL.dll");
                    myFunction();
            });

            function myFunction() {


                    setTimeout(function(){

                            var element = document.getElementById("SWFSquare");
                            swfobject.embedSWF("myProgram.swf", element, 300, 120, 10);

                    },10000);
            }
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I hope you have all needed information. Do not hesitate to ask me for more information.

So to remind. When I launch my script on 1st Windows under my Development Environment (IDE) everything works my DLL is loaded but when I try do load it with 2nd Windows by connected to index.php (=1st Windows as a server) the SWF works cause i get the message "HelloWorld" on the page but the dll is not loaded...

Can you help me ? I work on this for 2 weeks :-(.

Comment: You question is really unclear (at least for me). What are you trying to do ? That AS3 code is for your AIR app (server) or for the SWF loaded by your `index.php` ? Then, what's the relation of your AIR app and your SWF ? of course you should know that `NativeProcess` is only available for AIR ... Could you explain more your goal and your problem please ?

Comment: You cannot get an SWF running in the browser to load OS files (exe or dll etc) since that's a security issue. In the IDE you are testing an AIR app (which is itself running like an installed application).

Comment: First of all, Thank you guys for the quick response :-)

Comment: I'll give you all the details in next post below...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Thank you guys for the quick response :-)

So, I will answer **"Akmozo's** question :

As you see on the description of my ActionScript it will use "NativeProcess" to run the cmd that will execute a command to load myDLL.dll

So, I just have to execute the swf to start all of this. That is the relation between AIR app and swf. I work on FlashDevelop environment and every script "myProgram.as" that you "Build&Runs" create a "myProgram.swf" file. Once I get this file (automatically created) I just have to run it through the web by my "index.php" and more precisely by this code :

```
var element = document.getElementById("SWFSquare");
swfobject.embedSWF("myProgram.swf", element, 300, 120, 10);
```

So, when 2nd windows connected to index.php that run the myProgram.swf and finally I have not dll loaded...

That's my problem. Did I answer you "Akzmozo" ?

Now, for your answer **"VC.one"** I think it should be possible to do it on the environment I especially prepared.
That is to say :

- 1st Windows with last update and patches
- 2nd Windows with no update and no last Flash Player (currently is 19.0.0.206)

I'm an IT security researcher (student) and that's why I'm working now on a breach in Adobe Flash Player 19. Normally, it possible to do it because there is already a CVE on this work, and I would (re) create this scenario. But I'm always stuck on this problem and I think I missed something but I don't know what it is...

Comment: You don't need to use answer's area to answer our questions, you can use comments to do that.

Comment: I think that I understand your problem, or at least the situation. You should know that you can not use `NativeProcess` in Flash Player as it's available only for AIR, so I don't know how did you expect that your SWF should work in the browser? Your code is working in your "first" window because you are testing your AIR app, but in your "second" one, you will see just the "Hello, world" text but only that because Flash Player will fire an error after that. You can see that error using a debug version of Flash Player. That SWF file is compiled for AIR, so it's not 100% runnable in Flash Player.

Comment: Do you have a link to the specific CVE? Also check my answer, maybe it will help you understand.

Comment: Ok thank you for all the details.
Of course when I try to use the debug version of FlashPlayer and load the swf file, an error is popup :

"VerifyError: Error #1014: The class flash.desktop::NativeProcess is not found."
So obviously running the first part of the program that load a text message works fine but when I use nativeProcess to open cmd it doesn't work.

That's the CVE I've told you CVE-2016-0984 I give you the URL :
<<https://cxsecurity.com/cveshow/CVE-2016-0984/>>

And as I said, the "Infected" VM I created has the Flash&AIR versions 19 so according to this CVE it should work...

Comment: But I think it's just a problem of configuration... I have to add something in the "Infected VM" to work this program fine.

Thank you again, I will continue my research for the moment, I wait your answers once you will see the CVE.

Comment: Moreover I saw this two articles that talks about "How to run adobe AIR application through a web page. " 

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e15.html

AND this one 

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html

So, if I understood your warning "NativeProcess" is for AIR application so I can try to run an AIR application through my web page normally ?
I just need to adapt my script with details mentionned on the URLs above...
Can you tell me if its wrong ?

Comment: I dont see how that CVE's affecting two systems (AIR & Flash Player) means that any SWF on a website can run system files on my OS?? You misunderstand Its meaning. It mostly involves if the SWF is for example embedded into a PDF, when you open the PDF the SWF will read and execute a script code hidden in the PDF bytes. The script could get & install a virus from online URL. That kind of arbitrary code is CVe issue. Also that is just a basic example of problem such a CVE creates... (ie: I'm not saying the CVE is about PDFs etc)

Comment: Finally, those two links... the first one is just an AIR app installer shortcut placed on website (instead of d/load and then click to install from file manager, but achieves same thing). Second link is about using HTML code to make an AIR app instead of AS3 code. The example writes "Hello World" in html text not AS3 text field. The final product is still packaged as .air file or .exe file, to install as if published from IDE.

Comment: **Just face facts** you cannot put an SWF on a web browser that when someone in Japan clicks a button it tries to make their computer open photoshop.exe or maybe an SWF where in Brazil a user clicks to open blender.exe, how does it know if the user has such a file? How does it know if user is even on Windows PC? Who would trust Flash Player plugin if that is possible. Basic security sense does not allow it so stop searching for it...

Comment: "How does it know user is on WIndows PC".
As I said ealier, I dont put all my scripts, and that part is already done I can modify whatever I want and my script adapt to Macintosh, WIndows, and also mobile phones(iOS, Android).
But unfortunately, as you said I probably doesn't use the right way to create this scenario and I will explore what you said to me. Download something that contain the script. I mean "combine" two files in one. Combine "file.anything with myProgram.swf" and when users launch it that launch myProgram.swf.

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm always stuck on this problem and I think I missed something
>   but I don't know what it is...

@Akmozo is correct. Flash Player (browser) & AIR (OS app) are two **different** ways to run AS3 code as an application. **They don't always work the same** (an AS3 app rendered by browser Flash Player plugin is much more limited for security reasons, it cannot run programs on a computer otherwise hackers & virus creators would have found heaven with this power, spreading chaos via internet).

Also think about what happens if the SWF is run from a Mac or Linux browser? How do these OS load the dll (since it's a Windows-only file)? This breaks the rule that code in browser works same everywhere, regardless of platform.

Just to prove a point... update your textfield code to look like this below. In IDE testing it should say `(NP) Support = true` but when in browser you will get `= false`. Of course when its false then you cannot load the dll from a browser.

```
var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var txt:TextField = new TextField();

fmt.size = 32;
txt.text = 'Hello, world!' + '\n' +
'Width = ' + stage.fullScreenWidth + '\n' +
'Height = ' + stage.fullScreenHeight + '\n' +
'(NP) Support = ' + String(NativeProcess.isSupported); //# check if available

txt.setTextFormat(fmt);
txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

addChild(txt);
```